# What's the best option to process credit card payments in Django?

Tags: python, django, credit-card, payment

I need to process credit card payments on an app that provides a service outside the U.S. Given that Paypal it's not an option, I was wondering if there other services I could try. What would you recommend?

Comment: this question may be better answered at the startups page.

Comment: Try Stripe. It's got its own form and card processing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As mentioned in the previous answer, you need a [merchant account](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merchant_account) and a [payment gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_gateway).

I'd recommend [BrainTree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/) if you're processing enough payments that they'll accept you. They act as both if you want them to.  They also have a Python API for processing payments.  It will be much easier to set up.  I don't know if they accept customers from outside of the US.

[PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/) also offers a solution that allows you to process credit card payments without users having to go to the PayPal site.  It's called website payments pro, but I think it's only available in the US and the UK.

Otherwise, look at [Authorize.Net](http://www.authorize.net/) as a gateway (or shop around) and speak with you bank about a merchant account.

Nothing is built into Django or Python for this.

Answer (score 14):

Stripe has a Python library to accept credit cards without needing a merchant account: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python

Check out the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=python) and [FAQ](https://stripe.com/help/faq), and feel free to drop by our [chatroom](https://stripe.com/campfire) if you have more questions.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid PCI audits if the credit card details never touch your server... for example by using payment forms hosted on the servers of your chosen payment gateway provider.

I have used SagePay here in the UK (and built Django connectors for their service from scratch - sorry not on github yet...) and they offer payment forms you can display in an iframe on your site so they look part of your own checkout page, specifically to avoid the PCI issues.

Answer (score 3):

You need a [merchant account](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merchant_account), and a bank account that will accept the funds.

Comment: As well as the internet payment gateway (Authorize.net or others). Remember that accepting credit cards on your system then causes you to do PCI (Payment Card Industry) security audits, which can be a major money and time sink.